# Delete mounting directory after umount -l

Tags: linux, usb, openwrt, umount

I'm working on Linux OpenWrt where I have to mount and umount manually USB disks when they are attached to the router.

I'm using this script: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/writable_ntfs#with.a.custom.hotplug.script to mount and unmount automatically USB disks the problem is that it doesn't delete the mounting directory after `umount -l /dev/$device`. My application on the router needs to check if the USB disk is present or not by checking if `/mnt/sda1` exists or not

My question is: is it dangerous to add `rm -r sda1` after `umount -l /dev/$device`, or is there a risk that `rm -r sda1` will remove files in `sda1` ?

Comment: you could change your script to check 'mount | grep sda1' instead of checking if the directory exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be safe to delete the directory after the umount if you check for the success of the umount command before but I would suggest to change you script to check if the mountpoint it's listed in the mount table instead with `mount | grep sda1`

Comment: Your answer contradicts your comment (about checking the mountpoint). Also could you please provide reasoning as to why one way is better than the other?